# How to set 2 parameters fromdate and todate for datefield to solve error procedure or function expect parameter was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to select data between to date.my procedure :

```
alter procedure GetMah_Ko
    (@noe_p int,
     @kod varchar(2),
     @fromdate varchar(8),
     @todate varchar(8))
as
    select * 
    from tbl_dad
    where @noe_p = noe_p 
      and @kod = kod
      and @fromdate <= date 
      and @todate >= date

      return
```

And my C# code for calling it:

```
public List<Mahk> GetMah_Ko(int noe, string kod_, string from, string to)
{
    List<Mahk> Mahk_list = null;

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[]
           {
               new SqlParameter("@noe_p",noe),
               new SqlParameter("@kod",kod_),
               new SqlParameter("@date",from),
               new SqlParameter("@date",to)

           };

    using (DataTable table = SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSelectParameterCommand("GetMah_Ko", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param))
    {
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Mahk_list = new List<Mahk>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Mahk mahk = new Mahk();
                mahk.id_dad = Convert.ToInt32(row["id_dad"]);
                mahk.kod = row["kod"].ToString();
                mahk.date = row["date"].ToString();
                mahk.noe_p = Convert.ToInt32(row["noe_p"]);

                Mahk_list.Add(mahk);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Mahk_list;
        }
    }

    return Mahk_list;
}
```

and:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DAL.Mahk mahk = new DAL.Mahk();
        List<DAL.Mahk> Mahk_list;

        mahk.kod = lbl_kod.Text;
        Mahk_list = MahkDB.GetMah_Ko(2, mahk.kod,txt_fromdate.Text,txt_todate.Text);

        if (Mahk_list == null)
        {
            lbl_total_p.Text = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_total_p.Text = Mahk_list.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Session.Add("Msg_", "error: <br>" + ex.Message);
        Response.Redirect("~/ShowMessage.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

My problem is this error message:

> Function or procedure expects the parameter which was not supplied.

I know that error is related to my parameters, fromdate and todate. I think when I rename parameter to @date procedure works. But problem is how to set tow parameter for one column (date)?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `new SqlParameter("@date",from), new SqlParameter("@date",to)` be `new SqlParameter("@fromdate",from), new SqlParameter("@todate",to)`?

Comment: `@fromdate varchar(8)` I should **strongly** suggest you not use `varchar` for passing / storing dates in SQL Server.